# Calculate a specific $A$, $B$ in the general static spherically symmetric metric using geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

The Einstein field equations (EFE), leaving out $\Lambda $ for simplicity, are :

$$R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=-\kappa T_{\mu\nu}  \tag 1$$

From that, the general static, spherically symmetric metric can be derived :

$$ds^2 = -Bdt^2 + Adr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + sin^2\theta d\phi^2) \tag2$$

Now, I want to calculate a special metric ("toy metric") for $r>r_S$ with the following characteristics :

1. For $r>r_S$, it is ricci-flat, means, for $r>r_S$

   $$R_{\mu\nu} = 0 \tag3$$
2. The velocity $v(A,B,r)$ of probe masses in great distance from the centre is not dependent on $r$ , means

   $$\frac{\partial v(A,B,r)}{\partial r} = 0 \tag4$$
3. The metric shall explicitly not be asymptotically flat. $A$ is allowed to approach zero in the infinity.

From 1, one can derive that

$$A = \frac{1}{B}    \tag5$$

Therefore, the metric is well-defined from equation $(4)$ and equation $(2)$ .

Could you please help me how to progress further?

I would think that now, as the velocity of the probe masses is looked for, one has to write down the geodesic equations with $(2)$. From those, we can derive a function of the velocity which is dependent on $A$ , $B$ and $r$ . Equation $(4)$, then, using equation $(5)$, is a differential equation for the coefficient $A$. If we can solve this we can use $(5)$ again to derive the toy metric $(2)$ .

Please, help me to calculate through this.

Comment: $v(A,B,r)$ is the velocity of what exactly? A test mass on a circular orbit with radius r?

Comment: Is this some type of homework exercise?

Comment: Yes, exactly: $v (A,B,r)$ is the velocity of a test mass on a circular orbit with radius r.

Comment: homework exercise? I would say, no. Why do you ask? Its just a toy function to play a bit around with. I want to understand things better. :-)

Comment: The spherically symmetric metric can't be "calcuated" from the field equation without inputting values for the stress-energy tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (1) and (3), we know that for $r > r_S$ (the region you're interested in)
$$-\kappa T_{\mu\nu} = R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} = 0.$$

Hence, for $r > r_S$, we have vacuum. Since you are assuming spherical symmetry, [Birkhoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) ensures the solution is the Schwarzschild solution for $r > r_S$, i.e.,
$$\textrm{d}s^2 = -\left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right)\textrm{d}t^2 + \left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}\textrm{d}r^2 + r^2 \textrm{d}\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta \textrm{d}\phi^2$$
in geometrical units ($G = c = 1$).

Notice that spherical symmetry in GR is quite a strong assumption. Once you chose it, you pretty much fixed your spacetime up to the two functions $A$ and $B$. Notice also that the remaining conditions you listed are either not needed or inconsistent. Asking for spacetime to not be asymptotically flat is certainly inconsistent, due to Birkhoff's theorem.

Comment: Ok, I see. R = 0 (and so T=0) is not possible for constant velocities. Your solution is right and I'll accept it. (Although it doesn't fullfill all criteria - but that is obviously not possible as you showed.) I hope I'm allowed to write down another a bit different toy exercise to specify the problem I'm up to a bit more.